# How does a space vehicle which carries Curiosity or Spirit rover reach a planet?

Tags: mars, trajectory, debris, navigation

I don't know much science but was curious about it.

So, what I've seen in movies is that there are lot of objects in the space and many other space items (made of rocks, moving stars etc.). So when the vehicle is traveling to Mars, why doesn't it collide with those objects? How does it remains safe?

Secondly, how does it know Mars is this way? Does it calculate and correct its path itself from time to time so its trajectory is accurate or do NASA computers and scientists have control of it like a remote control car, or do they just define a trajectory in the beginning, define a target (Mars) and it keeps traveling on it (if yes, how can it be so accurate)?

Comment: For navigation: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33840/spacecraft-navigation. But about the trajectory, it is calculated mostly using computers which help decide on a trajectory that takes a feasible time and fuel. These calculations are based on orbital mechanics (mainly governed by gravity)

Comment: This question is really too broad, you should address separately each flight phase (from ground to Earth orbit, from Earth orbit to Mars orbit, Mars orbit insertion, de-orbit and landing on Mars). Moreover, you should forget most of what Hollywood movies could have teach you (movies are done to be visual, rocket science to be efficient), except maybe few movies such as [apollo13](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112384/)

Comment: Could you please edit to focus on one question? I will surely vote to reopen if you could do that, and I'm sure others will do too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Movies are misleading.

Space is enormous, and almost entirely empty. Even our ”asteroid belt” is mostly empty space; we have flown several missions straight through the belt to the planets beyond without hitting anything.

Low Earth orbit has collected quite a bit of space junk over the years, but even so, interplanetary probes spend only a very short time in that area, so the risks are very small.

As for your second question, the initial trajectories for missions to other planets as they leave Earth orbit are quite accurate, but we do have “remote control” and invariably make small midcourse corrections to the spacecraft. See this [question and answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30734/195) for more information.

Comment: * the initial trajectories for missions to other planets are quite accurate* this is also defined by computers before launch? Or after launch? I don't think at start, because initially every rocket flies at 90 degree upwards, not in direction of planet.

Comment: Correct, I meant the initial trajectory after departure from Earth orbit.

Comment: Okay. I got basic ideas, that's what I wanted to know :D Those articles and other answers are way too advanced andout of scope for me.

Comment: The articles might go into complicated description, but the concept is pretty simple. If you want some "hands on" experience, I'd recommend you give [Kerbal Space Program](https://www.kerbalspaceprogram.com/) a try. It's a rocket building/flying game, and according to a guy who worked at NASA, it's better than them at teaching orbital mechanics: https://xkcd.com/1356

Comment: @csiz said guy is also a comedian, so take that recommendation with a pinch of salt (and it’s not like he worked in a department related to orbital mechanics / was taught orbital mechanics by NASA).

Comment: @RussellBorogove I realise this is an extremely naive follow-up question (complete space-ex layman) but, why do we need corrections if space is empty and there's nothing to 'knock us off course'? Is it down to incorrect initial calculations?

Comment: @George I think the most significant errors are due to how rocket engines burn and gimbal. There are delays between a command being issued by the computer and a fuel valve closing and the rocket engine shutting off. Of course the effect is probably modelled, but it's not perfectly accurate. There are also mechanical errors in pointing the engine in the right direction. And small errors at the start of a trajectory make a big difference after millions of km in space.  The closer you are to the target, the less the errors matter, so mid way corrections are easier, but they use more fuel.

Comment: @George, to put some hard numbers on it, if you're going from an Earth parking orbit to a Moon orbit 100 km above the surface, it takes a pointing error of just 1/100 of a degree when firing the engines to crash into the Moon instead.