# What specifically does "Safe Mode" mean for Perseverance?

Tags: perseverance, safe-mode

An [older question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3633/what-is-safe-mode) asks about safe mode in general.  I am curious about Perseverance's safe mode in particular.  For instance, in the previous question, solar powered spacecraft start looking for the sun - not a problem here.  I'd also imagine that power isn't a super huge issue, so turning an antenna on or off, to me, doesn't make much sense.  So what happens in safe mode for this rover/cruise stage?

Comment: [NASA's Mars rover Perseverance is fine and out of 'safe mode'](https://www.space.com/mars-rover-perseverance-is-fine-exits-safe-mode.html)

Comment: I can't answer about Perseverance in particular. But in general, safe mode means a special mode in the state machine where only a few mode transitions are allowed, where only a few sensors are trusted, where most effector commands are inhibited (e.g., translational thruster firings), and where a perhaps limited set of communications equipment are used. Press releases strongly implied that translational thruster firings were inhibited in Perseverance safe mode as those articles stated JPL needed to move Perseverance out of safe mode prior to the first trajectory course maneuver.